# Is it possible to control execution order of angular services?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm building an Angular application and I have a problem with the callings of my webapi routes in my services.

The application has to be executed in two major steps:

1. Call OAuth server and get a valid token. This is done via two routes:
   a. Get an audience
   b. Get the token with a valid audience
2. Once I have a valid token, I can get my data (e.g. users, todo list ...)

my tokenService.ts

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenService extends ServiceBase {

    public token$: Observable<string>;
    private _token: BehaviorSubject<string>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        public request: RequestBase,
        public router: Router) {

        this._token = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
        this.token$ = this._token.asObservable();
    }


    generateToken(callback?: () => void, errorCallback?: (error: string) => void): void {
        // 1. get audience
        const audienceUrl = 'https://myoauthserverurl/api/audience';
        const postData = {
            // some data to post
        };
        const audienceHttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
            // some headers
        });

        this.request.post(audienceUrl, postData, audienceHttpHeaders).subscribe((audienceResponse: any) => {
            const audience = new Audience();
            audience.clone(audienceResponse);

            if (!audience.error.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                return;
            } else {
                // 2. get token with audience response
                const tokenUrl = 'https://myoauthserverurl/oauth2/token';
                const tokenPostData = ``;
                const tokenHttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
                    // some headers
                });

                this.request.post(tokenUrl, tokenPostData, tokenHttpHeaders, false).subscribe((tokenResponse: any) => {
                    const token = new Token();
                    token.clone(tokenResponse);

                    if (!token.error.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        console.log('Token generation failed: ' + token.error_description);

                        if (errorCallback !== null) {
                            errorCallback(token.error_description);
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    this.setToken(token.access_token);

                    if (callback !== null) {
                        callback();
                    }

                });
            }

        });

    }

    public setToken(token: string) {
        this._token.next(token);
    }
    public getToken() {
        return this._token.getValue();
    }

}
```

My app.component.ts calls

```js
tokenService.generateToken();
```

Then I load some component (e.g. UsersComponent.ts) and I display the list of my users. In the UsersComponent.ts constructor I inject the user service:

```js
constructor(public userService: UserService) {
    // do something
}
```

UserService.ts

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

    users$: Observable<User[]>;
    _users: BehaviorSubject<User[]>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        public request: RequestBase,
        public tokenService: TokenService) {

        this._users = new BehaviorSubject([]);
        this.users$ = this._users.asObservable();

        this.List();
    }

    public getUsers() {
        this._users.value;
    }

    public setUsers(value: User[]) {
        this._users.next(value);
    }

    public List() {
        this._users.next([]);

        this.tokenService.token$.subscribe(token => {
            const url = `https://webapi.url/users/list`;
            const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({...
                'mysecuredtoken': this.tokenService.getToken()
            });

            this.request.get(url, httpHeaders).subscribe((data: any) => {
                const response = data as User[];
                if (response !== null) {
                    this._users.next(response);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

But what happens is:

1. Call of the audience route
2. Call of the users/list route
3. Call of the token route

How can I controll theses services to have

1. Call of the audience
2. Call of the token
3. Call of the users/list

I hope it's clear enough :)
Thanks for your help.

[EDIT]
Thanks to **this.tokenService.token$.subscribe(...)** the **users/list** route is calling asynchronously (and so it will be ok after some times) but before that, there are many calls to the **users/list** route. I would like to avoid this behaviour and have clean calls to my webapi routes.
But as things are called asynchronously, is it worth it?

[EDIT]
this question is RESOLVED

Answer (score 0):

You're using `BehaviorSubject` which will return an initial value which you are setting here:

```
this._token = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
```

Your subscription `this.tokenService.token$.subscribe...` will be called straight away, with an empty value of ''.

Instead of using `BehaviorSubject`, try using `Subject`.

Comment: Even if I dont call the tokenService.token$.subscribe(), my routes callings are audience, users/list and then token. Which i wish to controll. I would like to be sure that my audience and token routes are called before any other so I'm sure to have a valid token.
But as the routes are called asynchronously, is t worth it?

Comment: This isn't something you should need to worry about. Even if you do call your routes the way you do, the users should never be retrieved until you get your token, that's what the subscribe should be waiting for.

Comment: So I need to trust the async calls and let them do the job. Thanks for confirming that :)

Is it ok to do that then?

this.tokenService.token$.subscribe(token => {

            if (token.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
...
}

Comment: Yes! That's what rxjs is all about: the flow of events. The only recommendation I would give it to remove some/all of your `.subscribe`'s and instead use the rxjs `pipe` operator instead. But that's just to improve the quality of your code, other than that, you are fine to use the `.subscribe()` notation.

Comment: Thank you Viqas. I can now see that all the unnecessary calls are not done.

Could you tell me more about your suggestion? How can I replace the .subscribe with the .pipe ? I'm not very at ease with the .pipe() notation.

Comment: [rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) is not an easy subject at all. To start with, I'd take a look at [this](https://malcoded.com/posts/rxjs-for-angular-devs/) and [this](https://medium.com/defmethod-works/implementing-rxjs-part-i-daaef12ec1c6) to get you started.